# webrtc: Don't ask for mic permission

Tags: ios, webrtc, microphone

I'm developing a WebRTC iOS application to receive video/audio streaming from a webcam.

The device only receives audio and video streams, does not collect audio and video, so do not need to apply for microphone permissions.

How can I prohibit the application of microphone permission?

Comment: I think that it does not matter on how you are going to use the microphone. If you are going to use it, then it is a default that you have to ask for permission on using the microphone. If ever you are going to submit it for App Store review, and you found a way to disable the asking for permission part, I don't think that the your app would pass the review.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create an `RTCVideoTrack` or `RTCAudioTrack` and don't add it to the `RTCMediaStream`.

Comment: I did not create RTCVideoTrack and RTCAudioTrack，but the device will still apply for microphone permissions.

Comment: Did you create an RTCMediaStream?

Comment: No,and I'm using this demo[link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc.git/+/master/examples/objc/AppRTCMobile/ARDAppClient.m),
I have commented on the following two lines of code,but the device will still apply for microphone permissions
[self createAudioSender];
[self createVideoSender];

Comment: That demo app is a really old API. WebRTC is changing everyday. The new APIs are better. Try building the WebRTC framework from scratch off the WebRTC repo

Comment: You can try using my demo app: https://github.com/redfearnk/WebRTCVideoChat